Different Name assigned to a Userform in the Project Explorer window and the Properties window
I recently downloaded a macro file from the website "https://www.contextures.com/exceldatavalselectpopup.html#download" while searching on how to create validation list with multiple outputs.
In the macros, userforms are used to achieve the required goal. But the userform name in the Project Explorer window is different from the Name used in the Properties window. (see image below). I always assumed the Properties window was used to define the name and it should be consistent throughout.
I cannot seem to figure how to achieve this effect. Does anyone know the underlying method to achieve this effect?
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem is resolved. The properties window was showing the name of the listbox and not the userform
